# Memory limit for keyboard extension

Tags: ios, iphone, keyboard, xcode8

I'm working on a custom keyboard and my keyboard is working fine. Recently when I run my keyboard extension I'm having a crash with the following message.

```
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

After doing some research I understand that this error/crash is because of memory problems. I would like to know how can I resolve this issue? And what is the maximum memory limit for the keyboard extension?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, the limit for keyboard extensions is about 40M - depends on the actual device. There is no definite documentation. You should use

```
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
 //do something
 }
```

in your code

Also, check leaks with instruments

Answer (score 0):

I found that ios custom keyboard works good within 30MB.
So try to keep memory within 30 mb for extension part.